# Python List not recognising values from a Database Table

Tags: python, mysql, list, pyodbc

I want to know why the code does not recognise that the Field value of 10 / 11 is within the list ['10 ', '11 '], as well as why it bypasses the initial if statement.

Any possible solutions would be greatly appreciated, below the code as well there are the print statements which produce after the code is run.

```
    TableRow = DBSelect.fetchall()
    for Field in TableRow:
        print(Field, "This is the currently looped ID")
        print(EList, "This is the EList")
        if Field in EList : # compares each  ID against the EList
            print(EList, "This is pre- modified EList")
            EList.pop([Field]) # removes the ID from EList
            print(EList, "This is post- modified EList")
            UnavailableE = UnavailableE + 1 #Add to the number of unavailable E
            print(UnavailableE, "This is the Unavailable e in the loop")
        elif UnavailableE == ECount: # if the UnavailableE is Equal to  ECount, then no ID available - runs this output
            print("No e available")
        else:  
            print("Not in list")
```

For further reference, here are the print statements that produce from this:

10   This is the currently looped ID

['10 ', '11 '] This is the EList

Not in list

11   This is the currently looped ID

['10 ', '11 '] This is the EList

Not in list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Field` is either not a string (a number?) or the string `"10"`, then it *isn't* in the list, as the list contains the strings `"10 "` and `"11 "` (note the trailing spaces).

Comment: Is there any way I could fix the list so that it simply just shows the strings 10 and 11? For the `Field` part (although I cut it out of the code provided for convenience) the values initially produced were formatted like so : `('10 ', )`. I used `Field.replace(" x ", "")` to edit this. Could this work for putting the EList values into the same format, and if they were formatted the same (without trailing spaces, speech marks etc), would it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
for Field in TableRow:
    Field = Field.strip()
    print(Field, "This is the currently looped ID")
    print(EList, "This is the EList")
```

add strip to strip begining and ending whitespace from field